# Do Scandinavian languages have liaisons?

Tags: pronunciation, germanic-languages

According to Wikipedia,

> Liaison (French pronunciation: ​[ljɛ.zɔ̃]) is the pronunciation of a latent word-final consonant immediately before a following vowel sound.

Scandinavian languages like Swedish, Norwegian, and Danish tend to drop final consonant sounds in speech, but do they experience liaisons when spoken?

For instance in Swedish: *Jag* is typically pronounced as *Ja*, but would *Jag är* be pronounced as *Ja gär*?

Does this happen in all Scandinavian languages? Is there any literature regarding this?

Comment: Are you telling us that you know as a matter of fact that [g] is pronounced in the phrase, in Swedish? Or are you asking "and is <jag är> pronounced [jɑ ar]?".

Comment: @user6726 The latter. I'm a beginning learner of Swedish, so most of my exposure to the language has been ceremoniously hyper-enunciated. I'm interested to know if liaisons occur in Swedish (and other Scandinavian languages).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the unpronounced citation consonants of  are not ever recovered phrasally before a vowel. There is the puzzle of knowing which orthographic consonants are unpronounced (Norwegian [rø] "red", Swedish [rød], but note that even before a vowel suffix, the  is gone in Norwegian ([røeste] "reddest"). I cannot parse Danish consonants, and I'd suggest consulting Basbøl's book if you want to know how that stuff is pronounced.

Comment: I agree. I can think of no instances of liaison in any Scandinavian language, either—including Danish. The only possible example I can think of is that _han_ ‘he’ and _hun_ ‘she’ nearly always lose their final /n/ before a consonant in rapid speech in Danish, but only facultatively before vowels. In slower or more careful speech, though, they don’t lose their nasal at all.

Answer (score 2):

Liaison exists in Danish but only in few words by inflections and word formation.

e.g.

*mand* [ma̝nˀ] "man" > *mandig* [ma̝ndi] "manly"

*valg* [va̝lˀ] "choice" > *valget* [va̝ljð̠ˠ̞] "the choice"

*valg* is also sometimes heard as [ˈvalˀj], implying the *j* is not yet totally latent.

Such rules have a certain universality, i.e. < nd > + -ig and the latent *j* which is pronounced followed by such an ending.

It is also worth to mention that a [k] can appear after [ŋ], because this may exist in other languages but often ignored. An experiment below shows that the [k] is latent. Some participants were asked to add a verbalization suffix *-ere*, which starts with a vowel, to a word ending with < ng > [ŋ], to form a new word. Most participants add a [k], so [pɛŋˀ] becomes [pɛŋkeːˀɐ] with the ending. This case is pretty as similar as the mentioned example of < nd >.